# How to check if pyodbc cursor is empty?

Tags: python, pyodbc

using pyodbc to query a MySQL database with SELECT. I need to determine if the query returned anything or not, the way I found that people were using is the rowcount, however this always returns -1 for me after some testing. I found this on the github wiki for cursor which I think describes my problem.

> rowcount
> The number of rows modified by the last SQL statement.
>
> This is -1 if no SQL has been executed or if the number of rows is unknown. Note that it is not uncommon for databases to report -1 immediately after a SQL select statement for performance reasons. (The exact number may not be known before the first records are returned to the application.)

I am wondering if either there is a way around this or if there is another way to do it, thanks.

Comment: If the result set is empty, `fetchall()` should return an empty list and `fetchone()` should return `None`. Both will be "falsy" when evaluated in a boolean context.

Answer (score 5):

I always check the length of the return results

res=newcursor.fetchall()
if len(res)==0:##means no results

Comment: I find `fetchall()` throws an exception if there was no data.

Comment: Check the exception, it has nothing to do with no data